# select 1st option in combobox by default in windows store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am using combo-box in windows store app, and having it populated through data binding. But while running, it selects an empty option. I want to select 1st option from items in combobox. I tried with setting `SelectedIndex="0"` in xaml, but it gives problem, bcz at the time of Component Initialization comboox has 0 elements. I don want to use code-behind. (`combo1.SelectedIndex = 0`). Any suggestion how to do that through xaml?

Edit:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="Repository" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <ComboBox Width="{StaticResource ComboWidth}" x:Name="repocombo" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Repositories}" SelectionChanged="SearchCombo_SelectionChanged">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
```

it gives 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException', but It works fine for me if i remove `SelectedIndex="0"` from it. Any pointer?

Comment: Show your full code..

Comment: added code, it gives probelm 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException'

Comment: Why don't you want code-behind for `combo1.SelectedIndex=0` when you have code-behind for `SelectionChanged="SearchCombo_SelectionChanged"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property to your ViewModel (or bindable data) that keeps the `SelectedItem` (and binded to `Combobox.SelectedItem`) and when you set the property `Repositories` you also set the `SelectedItem`:

```
Repositories = GetData();
SelectedItem = Repositories.FirstOrDefault();
```

and in your xaml code:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}"[...]
```

Comment: please try to add some explanation in your post if possible